# Use sudo in shell script

Tags: shell, sudo

I have access to another user's account using command:

```
sudo su - other_user
```

I do not have enter password. It seems that this is the only command that sudo allows me.

After that I'm able to perform several tasks like file copying and server restarting. I would like to automate those tasks so that a script can be executed by me, which would get other_user's rights and do what it has to do. However, `sudo` spawns another shell, which until I exit it blocks script execution. Is it possible to control that shell and to send commands into it from my script?

**Update 2011-11-01:**

I tried suggestions from the answers and both these commands:

```
sudo -u other_user whoami
sudo su - other_user -c "whoami"
```

ask for password.

Unfortunately, I could not find *sudoers* to look at settings. The situation annoys me a bit because a have privileges to do what I want to, but can't automate that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-c`option of the `su` command to execute commands as another user.
If needed, you can also use the output of those commands in your script, or in your shell.

Example:

```
[infeligo@server ~] cat /home/kenny/secretfile.txt  
cat: /home/kenny/secretfile.txt: Permission denied  
[infeligo@server ~] sudo su - kenny -c "cat /home/kenny/secretfile.txt"  
Dear diary: Today was a boring day at work. Good thing it's a friday!  
[infeligo@server ~]
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of su is not entirely necessary.

```
$ sudo -u other_user whoami
other_user
```